# Zurb Foundation Grid not working unless all columns have content

Tags: zurb-foundation

Heres my simple code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-3 columns">
     <br>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="large-3 columns">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I take out the `<br>`s the `<h1>` content will display on the left as if the `large-3 columns` never existed.

Is there a reason for this? And is there a better way to fix it other than adding dummy content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a better way to fix it. I always just put a `&nbsp;` or some lorem text.

You can also use push/pull classes to get the proper positioning while you fill your content.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. I would have sworn though that I didnt always have that problem. Odds are that I always had content in the columns and never noticed it.

Answer (score 2):

In Foundation 4, there's something called grid offsets.

```
<!-- more of what you're looking for -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-offset-3 large-6 columns">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this isn't the best way to handle part of a grid that needs to be centered. Foundation 4 also has a centered grid, so the most correct code would be:

```
<!-- centered column -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 large-centered columns">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Documentation on all this is found here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html